# Parsing いずれも言葉に出して教えられるものが文明の根底にある

Tags: verbs, parsing

Below is an excerpt from an article selected for an examination paper concocted by and aimed at Chinese.

> だが、文明の常識というものは、本来人間にとって、一つの暗黙の了解のようなものではなかっただろうか。自然の感じ方、起居動作の作法、基本的なモラルの感情など、**いずれも言葉に出して教えられるものが文明の根底にある**。

The official translation parses the last clause as

> いずれも言葉に出して教えられるものが、文明の根底にある

Which I agree, but I can't seem to rule out another possible structure, though less likely it appears:

> いずれも言葉に出して、教えられるものが文明の根底にある

I thought this could be resolved by confirming if this article adheres to 連用中止 instead of テ形接続, but it is a murky question in this case. There is such a sentence:

> 人間が細分化**され**、人間性が失われていくのと、**平行して**、他方ではそれを回復すると**称して**、空疎な政治スローガンがわれわれを偽りの常識に誘惑する。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

連用中止 and テ形接続 can coexist in one paragraph or in one sentence, and native speakers often use them almost randomly. In general, you should not rely on them to determine how to parse a sentence.

That said, a te-form meaning "by/with ～ing" tends not to be in 連用形 or followed by a comma. For example, 歩いて学校に行く and 包丁を使って野菜を切る are usually more common than 歩き学校に行く and 包丁を使い野菜を切る even in formal documents where 連用中止 is preferred.

In your case, you seem to know the author (basically) prefers the 連用中止 style, and 出して is not followed by a comma. So you may think this 言葉に出して教える tends to mean "to teach orally" rather than "to say, and (then) teach". (Of course, it is often the case that the context or your common sense is the only clue.)